# assigning computational resources to user with heroku

Tags: heroku, cloud

I would like to assign specific computational resources to a single user of my web application.
For example:

User 1 should have 8 cores and 8Gb memory

User 2 should have 16 cores and 64Gb memory

User 3 should have 32 cores and 128Gb memory

What is the recommended way doing this with heroku?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: "What is the recommended way doing this with heroku?"—there isn't any. If you want that level of control, get a VPS or manage your own infrastructure with Ansible or something.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That is kind of sad, but okay. I will probably look into other cloud services as well.